# Auto-Connect to Database When File Opens

Tags: toad

I have SQL files associated with Toad, so when I open them from Windows Explorer Toad runs and I see the file in a new Editor window.  However, I cannot figure out how to get the file associated with a connection.  If I click "New Connection", Toad connects to the db but it opens a new editor and the existing one remains unconnected.  How do I get Toad to auto-connect to my db when the file opens?  Or, after the file opens, how do I get that specific editor window connected?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an exact solution, but this may be about as close as you can get. On the Toad login window there's a column to auto connect a session. Check that column for the session you're interested in. Now when you dbl-click that file Toad will open the file and establish the connection; however, the file will be opened in a connection-less Editor. The first button on the Editor's toolbar is to change the session. If you click the down arrow on that button you can quickly associate that Editor containing your file with the session.